# Update localhost database using Xamarin Android on Local Network

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, localhost, local-network

How can I update the localhost database (MSSQL) using Xamarin.Android via Local Network (WiFi)?

I want to build an android application for a restaurant that the waiter will have and go and collect orders. The orders have to be kept locally on SQLite at first, and then pushed to the localhost/local server via WiFi/local network and updates the MSSQL database.

Then the order has to be printed out for the kitchen and the cash officer.

Comment: Create a REST/WCF service to do this.

Comment: Im sorry but you can there are SQL classes in Xamarin. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection/